# Marcar todos los checkbox de los nodos hijos de un nodo en un TreeView

Tags: c#, windows-forms

En un form tengo un treeview (tvArbol). El mismo, lo completo con todos los directorios y archivos de Windows. Para hacerlo, cada vez que expando un nodo, obtengo y completo el treeview con los nodos "hijos" del nodo expandido.

Todos los nodos tienen checkbox. Cuando marco el checkbox de un nodo, se marcan todos los checkbox "hijos" de éste.

El problema que tengo es que si el nodo "padre" aún no fue expandido (por ende, no se cargaron los nodos "hijos") la función para marcar los checkbox "hijos" obviamente sólo marca el checkbox "padre".

Intenté llamando a una función dentro de otra pero se me generan loops o algo no funciona porque la aplicación queda "tildada".

A lo mejor es algo muy sencillo, pero no veo la forma de hacerlo.

Pongo el código de lo que tengo hecho y funcionando hasta el momento:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DriveInfo unidad in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
        {
            TreeNode raiz = new TreeNode(unidad.Name);
            raiz.Tag = unidad.Name;
            raiz.ImageIndex = 0;

            raiz.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode());
            tvArbol.Nodes.Add(raiz);
        }
    }

    private void tvArbol_BeforeExpand(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Node.Tag != null)
        {
            CompletarArbolConDirectoriosYArchivos(e.Node, (string)e.Node.Tag);
        }
    }

    private void CompletarArbolConDirectoriosYArchivos(TreeNode nodo, string path)
    {
        nodo.Nodes.Clear();

        try
        {
            DirectoryInfo directorioPadre = new DirectoryInfo(path);
            DirectoryInfo[] subDirectorios = directorioPadre.GetDirectories();

            foreach (DirectoryInfo subDirectorio in subDirectorios)
            {
                TreeNode directorioHijo = new TreeNode(subDirectorio.Name);
                directorioHijo.Tag = subDirectorio.FullName;
                directorioHijo.ImageIndex = 1;

                directorioHijo.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode());
                nodo.Nodes.Add(directorioHijo);
            }

            List<FileInfo> archivos = new List<FileInfo>();
            archivos.AddRange(directorioPadre.GetFiles());

            foreach (FileInfo archivo in archivos)
            {
                TreeNode archivoHijo = new TreeNode(archivo.Name);
                archivoHijo.ImageIndex = 2;

                archivoHijo.Tag = archivo;
                nodo.Nodes.Add(archivoHijo);
            }

        }
        catch
        {
            // TODO: completar ...
        }
        finally
        {
            nodo.Tag = null;
        }
    }

    private void tvArbol_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        bool enProceso = false;

        if (enProceso) return;
        enProceso = true;

        try
        {
            MarcarNodos(e.Node, e.Node.Checked);
        }
        finally
        {
            enProceso = false;
        }
    }

    private void MarcarNodos(TreeNode nodo, bool marca)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode nodoHijo in nodo.Nodes)
        {
            nodoHijo.Checked = marca;
            MarcarNodos(nodoHijo, marca);
        }
    }
```

Una imagen de referencia:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: es que al expandir un nodo, deberias verificar si esta chequeado, y si es asi llamar a la funcion MarcarNodos para ese padre. eso no funciona?

Comment: @gbianchi el expandir un nodo o chequearlo deberían ser acciones independientes. Es decir, puedo expandir el nodo sin que haya nada chequeado. O puedo chequearlo sin expandirlo y que se me chequeen todos los subnodos. Lo primero lo tengo resuelto (cuando expando no se chequea nada, como debería ser). Lo segundo es lo que me presenta el problema, cuando chequeo sólo queda marcado el nodo padre, porque los hijos aún no existen. Si lo que me decis vos es al revés, es decir, al chequear verificar si está expandido, sí, lo probé, y es eso precisamente lo que me deja la aplicación "tildada".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que deberías hacer es que, al expandir un nodo, los nodos hijos se creen con la propiedad `Checked` igual que la del nodo padre:

```
    foreach (DirectoryInfo subDirectorio in subDirectorios)
    {
        TreeNode directorioHijo = new TreeNode(subDirectorio.Name);
        directorioHijo.Tag = subDirectorio.FullName;
        directorioHijo.ImageIndex = 1;

        directorioHijo.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode());
        directorioHijo.Checked = nodo.Checked; // Heredar propiedad Checked
        nodo.Nodes.Add(directorioHijo);
    }

    List<FileInfo> archivos = new List<FileInfo>();
    archivos.AddRange(directorioPadre.GetFiles());

    foreach (FileInfo archivo in archivos)
    {
        TreeNode archivoHijo = new TreeNode(archivo.Name);
        archivoHijo.ImageIndex = 2;

        archivoHijo.Tag = archivo;
        archivoHijo.Checked = nodo.Checked; // Heredar propiedad Checked
        nodo.Nodes.Add(archivoHijo);
    }
```

Comment: Excelente lo tuyo, muchas gracias! Funcionó perfecto y era más sencillo de lo que pensaba.

Comment: Pero si quiero marcar los checks de los Nodos Hijos según los valores de una taba o condición, cómo sería? Por ejemplo: Nodo Padre: VENTAS Nodos Hijos: Agregar, Modificar, Eliminar Sólo quiero que estén marcados Agregar y Modificar. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Con el evento Nodeclick podras obtener el check recientemente clickeado, de esta forma se detectara si fue un nodo hijo o padre; Si es un hijo, colocará al padre como 'indeterminado', excepto si todos los hermanos estan checkeados, colocará al padre como 'checkeado'; si es un padre, colocará a todos los hijos como 'chekeados' o 'no checkeados' según corresponda

```
        private void advTree1_NodeClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            check_nodos_padre(e.Node);
            check_nodos_hijos(e.Node);
        }

        private void check_nodos_padre(Node nodo)
        {
            if (nodo.Parent != null) //si el nodo padre no es nulo
            {
                var cont = 0; //para acumular cuantos nodos hijos estan activos o desactivados
                foreach (Node node in nodo.Parent.Nodes) //Recorrer todos los nodos del mismo nivel
                {
                    cont = cont + ((node.CheckState == CheckState.Checked) ? 1 : 0);
                    if (node.CheckState == CheckState.Indeterminate)
                    {
                        nodo.Parent.CheckState = CheckState.Indeterminate; goto adelantar;
                    }
                }
                if (cont == nodo.Parent.Nodes.Count) //si el numero total de nodos hijos estan activos o desactivados
                {
                    nodo.Parent.CheckState = CheckState.Checked;
                }
                else if (cont == 0)
                {
                    nodo.Parent.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked;
                }
                else
                {
                    nodo.Parent.CheckState = CheckState.Indeterminate;
                }
            adelantar:
                if (nodo.Parent != null) // si el nodo padre no es nulo
                {
                    check_nodos_padre(nodo.Parent);
                }
            }
            //advTree1.SelectedNode = nodo;
        }

        private void check_nodos_hijos(Node nodo)
        {
            if (nodo.Nodes.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (Node node in nodo.Nodes)
                {
                    node.Checked = nodo.Checked;
                    if (node.Nodes.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (Node node2 in node.Nodes)
                        {
                            node2.Checked = node.Checked;
                            foreach (Node node3 in node2.Nodes)
                            {
                                node3.Checked = node.Checked;
                                foreach (Node node4 in node3.Nodes)
                                {
                                    node4.Checked = node.Checked;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```